# Enum member not a type error

Tags: c++, enums, console, console-application, rubiks-cube

I'm making a Rubik's 2x2x2 cube simulator console app in C++ (the IDE I'm using is Code::Blocks). For now, I'm trying to implement all 6 face turns (L goes for left etc.) and the cube itself. Problem is, I'm getting an unexpected error that says:

> Error: White does not name a type
>
> Error: Red does not name a type
>
> ...and so on

Here's my code:

```
/// THIS PROGRAM SHOULD OUTPUT THE FASTEST SOLUTION TO A 2x2 RUBIK'S CUBE
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

/**
AVOID:
    - SAME MOVE THREE TIMES
    - REVERSE MOVE AFTER MOVE
*/

template<class T>
bool Check(vector<T> arr)
{
    const int a0 = arr[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] != a0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

enum Color {White, Red, Blue, Yellow, Orange, Green};

class Face
{
public:
    Face(Color cl)
    {
        c.resize(4, cl);
    }
    vector<Color> c;
};

class Cube
{
public:
    inline static void Turn(char c, bool reversed)
    {
        switch(c)
        {
            case 'L': L(reversed); break;
            case 'R': R(reversed); break;
            case 'U': U(reversed); break;
            case 'D': D(reversed); break;
            case 'F': F(reversed); break;
                case 'B': B(reversed); break;
            default: cout<<"ERROR: "<<c<<" is not a valid rubik's cube turn         notation.\n";
        }
    }

    bool Solved(){return true;}

private:
static Color aux[2];
static Face f1(White), f2(Red), f3(Blue), f4(Yellow), f5(Orange), f6(Green);
static void L(bool reversed) //f1, f2, f4, f5
{
    if(reversed)
    {
        aux[0]=f1.c[0];
        aux[1]=f1.c[2];

        f1.c[0]=f2.c[0];
        f1.c[2]=f2.c[2];

        f2.c[0]=f4.c[0];
        f2.c[2]=f4.c[2];

        f4.c[0]=f5.c[0];
        f4.c[2]=f5.c[2];

        f5.c[0]=aux[0];
        f5.c[2]=aux[1];

        return;
    }

    aux[0]=f5.c[0];
    aux[1]=f5.c[2];

    f5.c[0]=f4.c[0];
    f5.c[2]=f4.c[2];

    f4.c[0]=f2.c[0];
    f4.c[2]=f2.c[2];

    f2.c[0]=f1.c[0];
    f2.c[2]=f1.c[2];

    f1.c[0]=aux[0];
    f1.c[2]=aux[1];
}

static void R(bool reversed)
{
    if(!reversed)
    {
        aux[0]=f1.c[1];
        aux[1]=f1.c[3];

        f1.c[1]=f2.c[1];
        f1.c[3]=f2.c[3];

        f2.c[1]=f4.c[1];
        f2.c[3]=f4.c[3];

        f4.c[1]=f5.c[1];
        f4.c[3]=f5.c[3];

        f5.c[1]=aux[0];
        f5.c[3]=aux[1];

        return;
    }

    aux[0]=f1.c[1];
    aux[1]=f1.c[3];

    f1.c[1]=f2.c[1];
    f1.c[3]=f2.c[3];

    f2.c[1]=f4.c[1];
    f2.c[3]=f4.c[3];

    f4.c[1]=f5.c[1];
    f4.c[3]=f5.c[3];

    f5.c[1]=aux[0];
    f5.c[3]=aux[1];
}

static void U(bool reversed) //f2, f3, f5, f6
{
    if(!reversed)
    {
        aux[0]=f2.c[0];
        aux[1]=f2.c[1];

        f2.c[0]=f3.c[0];
        f2.c[1]=f3.c[1];

        f3.c[0]=f5.c[0];
        f3.c[1]=f5.c[1];

        f5.c[0]=f6.c[0];
        f5.c[1]=f6.c[1];

        f6.c[0]=aux[0];
        f6.c[1]=aux[1];

        return;
    }

    aux[0]=f6.c[0];
    aux[1]=f6.c[1];

    f6.c[0]=f5.c[0];
    f6.c[1]=f5.c[1];

    f5.c[0]=f3.c[0];
    f5.c[1]=f3.c[1];

    f3.c[0]=f2.c[0];
    f3.c[1]=f2.c[1];

    f2.c[0]=aux[0];
    f2.c[1]=aux[1];
}

static void D(bool reversed)
{
    if(reversed)
    {
        aux[0]=f2.c[2];
        aux[1]=f2.c[3];

        f2.c[2]=f3.c[2];
        f2.c[3]=f3.c[3];

        f3.c[2]=f5.c[2];
        f3.c[3]=f5.c[3];

        f5.c[2]=f6.c[2];
        f5.c[3]=f6.c[3];

        f6.c[2]=aux[0];
        f6.c[3]=aux[1];

        return;
    }

    aux[0]=f6.c[2];
    aux[1]=f6.c[3];

    f6.c[2]=f5.c[2];
    f6.c[3]=f5.c[3];

    f5.c[2]=f3.c[2];
    f5.c[3]=f3.c[3];

    f3.c[2]=f2.c[2];
    f3.c[3]=f2.c[3];

    f2.c[2]=aux[0];
    f2.c[3]=aux[1];
}

static void F(bool reversed) //f1, f3, f4, f6
{
    if(reversed)
    {
        aux[0]=f1.c[2];
        aux[1]=f1.c[3];

        f1.c[2]=f3.c[2];
        f1.c[3]=f3.c[3];

        f3.c[2]=f4.c[2];
        f3.c[3]=f4.c[3];

        f4.c[2]=f6.c[2];
        f4.c[3]=f6.c[3];

        f6.c[2]=aux[0];
        f6.c[3]=aux[1];

        return;
    }

    aux[0]=f6.c[2];
    aux[1]=f6.c[3];

    f6.c[2]=f4.c[2];
    f6.c[3]=f4.c[3];

    f4.c[2]=f3.c[2];
    f4.c[3]=f3.c[3];

    f3.c[2]=f1.c[2];
    f3.c[3]=f1.c[3];

    f1.c[2]=aux[0];
    f1.c[3]=aux[1];
}
static void B(bool reversed)
{
    if(!reversed)
    {
        aux[0]=f1.c[0];
        aux[1]=f1.c[1];

        f1.c[0]=f3.c[0];
        f1.c[1]=f3.c[1];

        f3.c[0]=f4.c[0];
        f3.c[1]=f4.c[1];

        f4.c[0]=f6.c[0];
        f4.c[1]=f6.c[1];

        f6.c[0]=aux[0];
        f6.c[1]=aux[1];

        return;
    }

    aux[0]=f6.c[0];
    aux[1]=f6.c[1];

    f6.c[0]=f4.c[0];
    f6.c[1]=f4.c[1];

    f4.c[0]=f3.c[0];
    f4.c[1]=f3.c[1];

    f3.c[0]=f1.c[0];
    f3.c[1]=f1.c[1];

    f1.c[0]=aux[0];
    f1.c[1]=aux[1];
}
};

int main()
{

    return 0;
}    
/// THIS PROGRAM SHOULD OUTPUT THE FASTEST SOLUTION TO A 2x2 RUBIK'S CUBE
```

I tried this declaration in main and it runs smoothly:

```
Face f(White);
```

Any ideas on why I'm getting this and how to solve it?

Comment: Try `static Face f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6;` and then inside `Cube`'s constructor: `f1 = Face(White); etc..`

Comment: Please pare your question down to a [mcve]. All the Rubik's cube stuff just gets in the way of the actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is your problem:

```
static Face f1(White), f2(Red), f3(Blue), f4(Yellow), f5(Orange), f6(Green);
```

Basically it doesn't like the way you are initializing f1 et al.

[Static variables should be defined outside of the class according to this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019856/c-initialize-static-variables-in-class)

[Related: Why it doesn't make sense and why you can't initialize static members in the constructor.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323927/why-cant-i-initialize-my-static-data-member-in-my-constructor)

Then just as a general observation: IMO you are using static more than you need to

Answer (score 0):

```
Face f(White);
```

declares and defines an instance `f` of type `Face` and constructs it with argument `White`.

But

```
static Face f1(White), f2(Red), f3(Blue), f4(Yellow), f5(Orange), f6(Green);
```

within the class definition tries to declare six static element-functions, returning an instance of class `Face`. A function declaration needs parameter types in the parenthesis, but you pass in enum elements `White`, `Red`, etc. which the compiler complains about.

You probably want to have six instances of class `Face` constructed with the given colors.

To achieve that, replace the line by

```
static Face f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6;
```

and outside the class define them with

```
Face Cube::f1(White);
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are curious what it *is* doing, then remember that:

```
int foo(int);
```

Is a declaration for a function.  In your class (simplified):

```
enum Face { White, Red, Blue };
class X {
    static Face f1(White), f2(Red), f3(Blue);
};
```

This is attempting to declare (without providing an implementation) a class that has 3 static **functions**, *f1*, *f2*, and *f3*, all returning a Face.  *f1* takes an argument of type White, *f2* takes an argument of type Red, and *f3* takes a Blue.  But *White*, *Red*, and *Blue* are not types, they are enumerators.  That's why you're getting this error.  This is another variation of "C++'s most vexing parse".

However, to make it work, you can use an initializer rather than parenthesis to declare variables, and you must declare the static members *const*:

```
enum Face { White, Red, Blue };
class X {
    static const Face f1{White}, f2{Red}, f3{Blue};
};
```